# How to update IBOutlets of a custom UICollectionViewCell in a separate .xib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I implemented a UICollectionView inside a UIViewController. The TopCell is created in a separate .xib file and it is implemented in a separate .h and .m files with the IBOutlets and IBActions. The rest of the cells are implemented in the same UIVIewController (The reason is because I added [this](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/) Parallax effect).

I would like to modify the info of the IBOutlets (labels and buttons) that are in the TopCell from the viewcontroller. This is how I am trying to modify but it is not working (I tried in cellForRowAtIndexPath and in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind).

```
 CSHeaderRanking *topcell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"TopCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
topcell.myScoreValueLabel.text = @"32";
```

How should I do it? And in which method should I add it?

This is my viewcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Parallax Effect, UICollectionView
    // Locate the layout
    CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout *layout = (id)self.collectionView1.collectionViewLayout;
    if ([layout isKindOfClass:[CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout class]]) {
        layout.parallaxHeaderReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 220);
        layout.parallaxHeaderAlwaysOnTop = YES;
    }

    // Locate the nib and register it to your collection view
    UINib *headerNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CSHeaderRanking" bundle:nil];
    [self.collectionView1 registerNib:headerNib
           forSupplementaryViewOfKind:CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader
                  withReuseIdentifier:@"TopViewCell"];
    [self.collectionView1 registerClass:[CSHeaderRanking class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TopCell"];


    //get the position of the user and the ranking (this should update the IBOutlets in the CSCellUser.h)
    [self getUserRanking];

    //get the ranking of users (this updates each cell of the ranking in cellForItemAtIndexPath) 
    [self getRanking];

}


- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
      numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ranking count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"UsersCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UserRanking *user = [ranking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

    //Fill the cell
    UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    usernameLabel.text = user.username;

    UILabel *scoreLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", user.score];

    return cell;
}

//Set TopViewCell
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
    if ([kind isEqualToString:CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader]) {
       UICollectionReusableView  *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind withReuseIdentifier:@"TopViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return reusableview;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access IBOutlets of a UICollectionViewCell from a UIViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079836/how-to-access-iboutlets-of-a-uicollectionviewcell-from-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: You asked this question 5 days ago.